# How can I plot a Dataframe in Python by grouping a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like this:
[image]

I want to group it by destination and plot sorted value of travelers by bar chart. Now my question: I used `o1_p1.groupby(by = "Destination").sum().plot(legend=True,kind = 'bar')`

and I got this kind of plot that is not clear!
[image]

And the second question how can I sort X-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calculating `sort_values()`

```
s = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({"Destination":np.random.randint(1,20, s)
              ,"Travellers":np.random.randint(300,10000, s)
             })

df.groupby(by = "Destination").sum().sort_values("Travellers").plot(legend=True,kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

### customise x-axis

You can change many parameters,  take a look at `matplotlib` documentation.  Below demonstrates create figure and axis first,  use in `pandas plot()` then change as you wish.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = 150
df = pd.DataFrame({"Destination":np.random.randint(1,50, s)
              ,"Travellers":np.random.randint(300,10000, s)
             })

# create figure and axis so that parameters can be changed
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,6])
df.groupby(by = "Destination").sum().sort_values("Travellers").plot(ax=ax, legend=True,kind = 'bar')
# bold the text
ax.set_xlabel(ax.xaxis.get_label().get_text(), weight='bold', fontsize=12)
# show every second label to prevent conjection...
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]: label.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I make more space between bars? ( as you can see in my plot all x_values are mixed)

Comment: I've updated answer,  you can control and manage all aspects.  I've just shown show every second label so they don't overlap in plot...